# Do not match the regex if a negative lookbehind / lookahead is matched

Tags: regex

I was trying to match some numbers based on certain conditions.

- Match the numbers if the unit are 'km/h'
- do not match the numbers if unit is cc or if there is a $ sign in front of number

I was trying to use negative lookbehind and lookahead like below to test out for the condition for cc. But it only omited one "0" in my test sample.

```
\d{1,4}(?!cc)
```

and my test sample:

```
100.2km/h
3000cc, 
$2/km
```

I will need to match 100.2, and should not match 2, and 3000..

Comment: And what is the regex flavor? Can it support possessive quantifiers/atomic groups, lookbehinds? Note that if you want to only match when there is `km/h`, the answer is `\d*\.?\d+(?=\s*km\/h)`.

Comment: Would this work? https://www.debuggex.com/r/I1kO4bIrLiWjIC6R

Comment: From what I understand, you need [`(?<!\$)\b(\d*\.?\d+)(?=$|\D)(?!cc)`](https://regex101.com/r/vY2yL7/1). However, your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Using negative lookbehind and lookahead you could use:

```
(?<!\$)([\d.]+)(?=km\/h)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GH78mnjyOq88LySX)

Comment: Can the person down voting please explain why these answers aren't useful?

Comment: Such downvoting without leaving a comment must be forbidden on SO. +1 to make up for that.

Comment: I find `[\d.]+` a bit permissive, e.g. `....` will match. PS: I'm not the serial downvoter :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
(?<!\$)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=km\/h)
```

It is checking there is no $ present before the number and must have a `km/h` after the number. For the number matching I am considering the digits after decimal point using `(\.\d+)?`

You may use anchors `^` and `$` to match the whole string too (if you want).

Comment: Plus-one to make up for a comment-free downvoting.

Comment: but for the sake of doing the test completely, when I try to do (?!cc) on 3000cc, my sample would select 300 instead of select nothing, how should i work around that?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @MacroMan, you can **include digits into the negative lookbehind** to ensure matching only "whole" numbers:

```
(?<![\$\d])(\d+\.?\d+)(?=km\/h)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Try it on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RwWAZWBNkDtRE2Gz)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write a general regular expression for finding numbers in text that match your criteria then look-ahead and look-behind are a reasonable approach. The trick is to note that the negative look-behind must match on both a `$` and a digit, otherwise it would just start the match from the second digit of the number. So I think the solution you are looking for is:

```
(?<![$.]|\d)([\d.]+)(?=km\/h)
```